# document.getElementById is returning null or undefined everytime

Tags: javascript, html

**Javascript code is**

```
function addConformationNo(){   

  var confirmationNo = document.getElementById("addedconfirmation").val();    

  alert(confirmationNo);

}
```

and I'm calling `addConformationNo()` function on click of a button

When the `addConformationNo()` function is executed, the function call to `document.getElementById` returns null everytime. Why? Any clues?

Comment: Maybe you don't actually have an element with that ID?

Comment: you use a jQuery function on a DOM element. Instead use `$("#addedconfirmation").val()` or `document.getElementById("addedconfirmation").value`

Comment: or `document.getElementById("addedconfirmation").value`

Answer (score 5):

Either:

1. You don't have an element of that id
2. You are calling the function before the element exists
3. You are misreading the error message

DOM elements do not have `val` methods associated with them, so you are likely to get a "Property is undefined or not a function" error, but that is complaining about `val` not the return value of `getElementById`.

Access the `value` property instead.

```
var confirmationNo = document.getElementById("addedconfirmation").value;
```

Comment: var confirmationNo = document.getElementById("addedconfirmation").value;  using this also returning empty value.

Answer (score 0):

```
var confirmationNo = document.getElementById("addedconfirmation").value;
```

will do.

You can also inspect element by right clicking on the browser or you can check the javascript console in your browser.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type=text/javascript>
function addConformationNo(){

var confirmationNo = document.getElementById("addedconfirmation").value; 

alert(confirmationNo);

}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<input type = "text" name = "addedconfirmation" id = "addedconfirmation" />
<input type="submit" onclick="addConformationNo();">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: var confirmationNo = document.getElementById("addedconfirmation").value; this also returns empty and there is no error shown in error console

Comment: If you post your html code too.It seems like you are using wrong id or something like that?

Comment: My HTML code is <input type = "text" name = "addedconfirmation"  id = "addedconfirmation" value = "" placeholder = "Enter confirmation no"/> and <input type = "button" value = "Save" onclick = "return addConformationNo();" />

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting such a message for every element. Then you may have included the javascript file at the beginning of HTML on the top instead of the bottom.